# All NOT IN can be converted to NOT EXISTS?

Tags: sql, not-exists

I have a table, FilesContainsFiles that is a join table:

- FilesContainsFiles(IDContainerFile, IDContentFile)

I would like to know which contained files are only contained in the specific container file.

For example, I have the fileA that contains file01 and file02 and a fileB that contains file01.

I would like to know which files are only contained in the fileA. So with NOT IN I have:

```
select * from FilesContainsFiles 
where IDContentFile NOT IN(
select IDContentFile from FilesContainsFiles 
where IDContentFile IN(select IDContentFile 
from FilesContainsFiles where IDContainerFile NOT IN (64)))
```

NOTE: I am using NOT IN and IN because I would like to specific a many fileContainer. For only one container I can use an equal comparison.

However, when I try to use NOT EXISTS and I don't get results. I try something like that:

```
select * from FilesContainsFiles 
where NOT EXISTS(select * from FilesContainsFiles where IDContainerFile <> 64)
```

Is it possible to use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `IN` query can be written as

```
select * from FilesContainsFiles 
where IDContentFile NOT IN(select IDContentFile 
from FilesContainsFiles where IDContainerFile <> 64)
```

and the `EXISTS` version as

```
select * from FilesContainsFiles fcf
where NOT EXISTS (select * from 
FilesContainsFiles fcf2
where IDContainerFile <> 64
and fcf.IDContentFile = fcf2.IDContentFile)
```

Comment: thank so much. The NOT IN version is more simple than my version and the not exists version works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this to achieve the same goal (only choose content files which are contained in container with ID=64):

```
SELECT IDContentFile, GROUP_CONCAT(IDContainerFile) AS IDContainers 
FROM FilesContainsFiles
GROUP BY IDContentFile
HAVING IDContainers = "64";
```

Comment: This is mysql-only (because of `group_concat` and using an expression alias in `having`).